# Error -32000 testing block.basefee in bsc testnet

Tags: solidity

I have to deploy a smartcontract from this url : https://blog.soliditylang.org/2021/08/11/solidity-0.8.7-release-announcement/

here code contain :

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: none

pragma solidity >=0.8.0 <0.9.0;

contract Basefee {
    function basefee_global() external view returns (uint) {
        return block.basefee;
    }
    function basefee_inline_assembly() external view returns (uint ret) {
        assembly {
            ret := basefee()
        }
    }
}
```

i have test it on JavaScript (london) in remix get result 0, but after deploy at bsc testnet and call some function get error like that :

```
{
  "code": -32000,
  "message": "invalid opcode: opcode 0x48 not defined"
}
```

someone might solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the BSC doesnt implement EIP1559, and therefore the concept of "base fee"  doesnt exist on it